# Creating an editable document via java web application

Tags: java, ms-word

I am looking for a convenient method to export some data from my database into a form that would be editable afterwards. The perfect scenario would be to export a word document, and perhaps a brutally simple solution would be to generate HTML and copy/paste it into Word.

I've looked at several open source libraries for generating word documents, but they seem a bit too simple or incomplete. I need support for tables and embedded images and control over formatting the fonts, table borders etc. (too much formatting seems to be lost when copying html and pasting into word).

Although Word is the end format, it'd be fine to generate it in any format that word would be able to open and subsequently save as DOCX.

I really haven't been able to find anything about generating ODT files (server side without client installation).

I would just dive into the ASPOSE libraries, but it'll take ages (and significant pain) to get a purchase order sorted out so I need to make sure its the only viable option before taking that route.

I could generate it as an excel file and copy that to word - this is looking like the best option currently.

Comment: I think you will find HTML the easiest and most foolproof over time. You just have to limit your HTML and fiddle with it until you get some that is pastable into Word. (But Rich Text is another option, as is PDF. Both can be generated in java and streamed out.)

Comment: It might not be Java but why not use VBA to access the DB and generate the document?

Comment: Aspose component can read and write to both DOCX and HTML, but from a supported programming language. If you want to edit the document from a web app, I would recommend an HTML editor like CKEditor. Bottom line is to use widely accepted and supported products/standards. Test your most complex documents with Aspose to do DOCX to HTML, load HTML in CKEditor, edit, then do HTML to DOCX with Aspose again.

Comment: docx4j also rounds trips XHTML quite nicely with CKEditor.  But as an alternative to XHTML to docx, have you considered content control data binding?

Comment: Thanks, I don't need to edit the document in the web app, its more a case of export it, then massage in Word. HTML is proving difficult to format appropriately, Excel is *nearly* there, it just won't copy the images quite right...

Comment: I am also looking for a similar solution were you successful or did to resort to Aspose.

Comment: I gave up and just used Excel and worked around the problems. Its not the seamless experience I'd prefer but understanding the Licensing and budget approval for Aspose just proved too hard. Software companies are leaving a lot of money on the table by making it all too complicated and hard.

Comment: I'm also now using Excel and Word macros to post process the excel and word documents to make it more polished.